# What are the biases of the new civilizations?

Tags: civilization-5-gods-and-kings

This question is related to an earlier question about the various civilization biases I asked here ([Why does Gandhi want to nuke me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58009/why-does-ghandi-want-to-nuke-me)). The expansion added numerous new civilizations so I was looking for an updated list of traits and biases for the various civilizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Civilization 5: Gods and Kings Traits]

A list of all the AI traits for the expansion and the DLC civilizations. ([Embiggen link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7c91.jpg))

### Competetiveness

**Victory**: The chance of getting the "they think we try to win in a similar fashion" diplomatic penalty

**Wonder**: Chance of getting the "they covet wonders we built" diplomatic penalty

**City-state**: Chance of getting the "we compete for same city-states'" diplomatic penalty Boldness: unknown

**Diplo balance**: Unknown, possibly chance for getting diplomatic penalties for attacking or denouncing a nation you have declarations of friendship with.

**Denounce Willingness**: Willingness to use denouncements

**Friendship Willingness**: Willingness to declare friendships

**Loyalty**: chance of them backstabbing someone (war or denouncement)

**Neediness**: how likely they are go ask for resources/gold with Declaration of Friendliness active

**Forgiveness**: chance of the AI forgiving old grudges (diplomatic penalties)

**Chattiness**: how likely they open up the screen and comment.

**Meanness**: unknown

### Diplomacy

**War/Hostile/Guarded/Afraid/Friendly Neutral:** How likely they are to decide upon having one of the stated attitudes, considering all other modifiers already in place

**Deceptive**: how likely their stated attitude does not reflect their real attitude. This is exactly the same model as was used in CIV4 (can declare at friendly, pleased, cautious) but otherwise does not affect current diplomacy (an AI that can declare war at Friendly and is thus deceptive, will still give you 300 gold for a luxury resource).

### CS-Biases

**Ignore/Friendly/Protective/Conquest/Bully:** how likely the AIs not to care / invest into (and do quests) / defend (civ X declares protection over CS Y) / conquer a city state.

### Flavors

**Offense/Defense/City-defense:** how likely they are to invest into offensive/defensive units or city defenses (walls, castles, military bases).

**Military training:** chance of building Barracks, Armories, Stables etc.

**Recon/Ranged/Mobile/Naval/Naval Recon/Air:** Chance to build certain unit types

**Naval Growth/Naval Tile Improvement/Water Connection:** Chance to build lighthouses, seaports, fishing boats, harbors

**Expansion/Growth/Tile improvement/Infrastructure:** how likely they are to build settlers, workers, make tile improvements, roads

**Production/Science/Gold/Culture:** chance of building production, science, gold, culture buildings and focus on working those tiles

**Happiness:** chance of building happiness buildings

**Great People/Wonders:** first unknown, could be chance of building gardens or employing specialists, the other one is for chance of building wonders

**Religion**: chance of building religious buildings

**Diplomacy/Spaceship:** how likely they are to go for UN or Science victory

**Nuke/Use Nuke:** how likely they are to build Manhattan project and to build nukes. Use nukes is the likelihood

**Espionage:** how likely the civs are to make use of spies and build espionage buildings

Comment: [Here's the image source](http://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/16gr41/the_big_chart_of_ai_bias_what_they_are_likely_to/).

Comment: @Yves Thanks for that, saw it on a different reddit post but couldn't find the original.