# Why is Gandhi so aggresive?

Tags: civilization-5

When playing Civilization the Gandhi AI seems very aggressive in its use of nuclear weapons.

Real live Gandhi has a reputation of not being aggressive at all, is there a reason why the creators of Civilization made him so aggressive in the game?

Although the answer [why does Gandhi want to nuke me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58009/why-does-ghandi-want-to-nuke-me) explains that Gandhi has a high probability of nuking people, it does not explain why the developers made this choice.

Comment: Actually, it is explained in that other question, in one of the lower voted answers. It's a bug in one of the first Civ games.

Comment: This is a duplicate and all these answers are just repeating information from the other question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is carry over joke that originated from previous edition bug.

Quote from [civ wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Gandhi_(Civ5))

> The biggest thing that stands out about Gandhi is his nuke ratings of
>   12. These are 4 points ahead of the closest leaders (Catherine, Montezuma, and Shaka with an 8 in both categories), making him hands
>   down the most nuke-happy leader in the game. This is intended more as
>   a shout-out to previous games than anything else: in the original
>   Civilization, due to a bug, the normally peaceful Gandhi would
>   suddenly become extremely aggressive if he adopted a "peaceful" form
>   of government, such as Democracy, which was often close to the time
>   when nukes would be invented.

Comment: The bug that was mentioned was caused by an integer overflow error.  In Civ 1, Gandhi was given the lowest aggression level of 1 in the code.  However, if a player adopted democracy, their aggression level decreased automatically by 2.  1 - 2 = -1.   Since you can't have a negative aggression level (from a code standpoint) it looped back around to 255 (the maximum 8-bit unsigned integer), making Gandhi super aggressive.  [Fun article here](http://kotaku.com/why-gandhi-is-such-an-asshole-in-civilization-1653818245) with [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of3pU.jpg).

Answer (score 8):

While I don't know developers motivation behind this choice, I always thought they took the following [quote from Ghandi](http://www.mkgandhi.org/ebks/mahatma-gandhi-volume-ten.pdf) to the next level:

> There was a time when people listened to me because I showed them how
>   to give fight to the British without arms when they had no arms and
>   the British Government was fully equipped and organised for an armed
>   fight. But today I am told that my non-violence can be of no avail
>   against the communal madness and, therefore, people should arm
>   themselves for self-defence. If this is true, it has to be admitted
>   that our thirty years of nonviolent practice was an utter waste of
>   time. We should have from the beginning trained ourselves in the use
>   of arms. But I do not agree that our thirty years' probation in
>   nonviolence has been utterly wasted. It was due to our non-violence,
>   defective though it was, that we were able to bear up under the
>   heaviest repression and the message of independence penetrated every
>   nook and corner of India. But as our non-violence was the nonviolence
>   of the weak, the leaven did not spread. Had we adopted non-violence as
>   the weapon of the strong, because we realised that it was more
>   effective than any other weapon, in fact the mightiest force in the
>   world, we would have made use of its full potency and not have
>   discarded it as soon as the fight against the British was over or we
>   were in a position to wield conventional weapons. But as I have
>   already said, we adopted it out of our helplessness. **If we had the
>   atom bomb, we would have used it against the British**.
>   *[emphasis mine]*

Answer (score 7):

It's a reference to one of their previous games. Ghandi was so peaceful that once a certain tech or political action(can't remember which it was) it made him go below 0 in aggression and that caused the game to rollback it so instead of being -1 in aggression he became a 255. Keeping Ghandi aggressive and nuke-happy ever since has been an inside joke sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

It is a joke referencing a severe bug in civ I, that was so popular and hilarious that the developers kept the essentials of it in place in all future releases.

If you want an entertaining read, this explains it rather well : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ipS7.jpg

Otherwise the essentials are:

- Civ AI leaders had set values for parameters like aggression and building tall vs wide (etc...) on a scale of 1-10 that were used to weight AI behaviour
- These values could be affected by the government type selected by the AI (Fireaxis wanted to create peaceful democracies, aggresive despots etc...)
- Democracy was a late game tech, and reduced a leader's aggression by 2 points
- Gandhi loved democracy, and would rush to implement it
- Gandhi had a default aggression of 1/10. So -2 aggression left him at -1 aggression, something the developers hadn't really planned for, and the C code interpreted this as aggression of 255/10.
- Gandhi consequently became the most aggressive thing in the game, round about the time that nukes could be discovered.
- Psycho Gandhi really wants some of those nukes...
- Thus, from nowhere and with zero provocation, human players found their favourite safe-bet ally and trading partner scouring everything in reach with nuclear hellfire.  It was a memory that really stuck with people....